# Does %elemental resistance work without any elemental resistance gear?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I crafted some gems with +7% elemental resistance. I socketed one of those gems into a chest piece.

Is there something like a base resistance against the elements? If I don't have any other equipment with any type of elemental resistance, is my +7% elemental resistance of 0 meaningless? Or does this mean 7% less damage from any source of elemental magic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no flat elemental resistance stat; **all** elemental resistances reduce a percentage of the incoming damage. Your gem is useful, don't worry!

As a side note, a Dokkalfar starting with the Earth deity, Gaea, starts out with 5% elemental resistance. If that effect required something else to make it work, it would uniquely be the **only** race/deity choice that doesn't affect you at the start of the game.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have proof of this, but my assumption is that you would take 7% less damage from elemental magic.